# Blank Screen after adding CSS file

Tags: python, css, django

so i am following python django tutorial from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html#figure-5

Downloaded Bootstrap Compiled CSS & JS version (Bootstrap v4.0.0). But when i run it on cmd promt. it shows blank screen only, but when i remove the css file, it shows basic HTML page. I reckon there is some problem in linking my css file.

the directory looks like

```
myproject/
 |-- myproject/
 |    |-- boards/
 |    |-- myproject/
 |    |-- templates/
 |    |-- static/
 |    |    +-- css/
 |    |         +-- bootstrap.min.css.map    <-- here
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

DEBUG is true, django.contrib.staticfiles is installed

My settings.py file code looks like

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Home.html file looks like

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Boards</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- body suppressed for brevity ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: check in Inspect toll bar.  Could be a chance  body has  display none property

Comment: What do you mean by _"running on cmd"_? Also, am I correct assuming that unclosed bracket on STATICFILES_DIRS and `*.min.css.map` instead of `*.min.css` mistakes/typos are present in your post only, not in project?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Hi, Yes they are only present in the post. I've corrected them now. By cmd i meant command prompt.
I'd tried after adding .map as well. It doesn't work either way  :(

Comment: @PDSSandeep This is what chrome is showing
html {
    display: block;
    color: -internal-root-color;
}

Comment: Still no idea how is "command prompt" related to your situation. Issue does not seem to be related to Django configuration. Your HTML and/or CSS are broken or affecting rendering in the way not what you think.

Comment: @Swat Looks like your CSS is overriding with the display, visibility or floating values